# Can I force GWT recompilation in Super-Dev when some resource has changed?

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have a bunch of generated source files which then are used in a GWT-based code. When I'm just recompiling the project everything is fine but when in comes down to a super-dev mode - that's where I'm completely lost.

The question is following - is there's a way I can tell to the GWT launched in a super-dev mode that changes in this particular folder should trigger recompiling of the whole project?

Files I'd like to monitor changes belong to a java package but are not java or "*.gss" files.

**What I've tried so far** is to invoke [watcher-maven-plugin](https://github.com/rzymek/watcher-maven-plugin) which just reruns `mvn generate-sources` whenever file in a given folder changes. I don't like this approach because it looks a bit redundant and over-engineered to me - after all, GWT code server somehow triggers source generation when *.gss files are changing, that gives a hope that somehow I can shove in other type of files as well.

Comment: How are those non-java files used by your project? Using a GWT generator ?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer basically bunch of css-preprocessor files that are compiled into gss